# Correctly formatting <pre> and <code> blocks in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, tailwind-css, pre

I have the following `<code></code>` block in my Vue.js application as follows, (using TailwindCSS classes):

```
<code class="block whitespace-pre overflow-x-scroll">
   {{ dataset.bibTex }}
</code>
```

However, on the page, this looks as follows:

[image]

I was wondering, what have I done wrong in formatting this block? Do I need to regex replace anything? I've tried trim, and regex replacing characters at the start and end, but nothing seems to work...

Comment: How would you like it to be formatted? Is it just the extra space at the beginning?

Comment: how confident are you that `dataset.bibTex` doesn't have whitespace? can you show what you tried to remove the whitespace exactly?

Comment: looking at the doc for [whitespace-pre](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace#pre) you might try removing that class or making code block one line

Comment: @depperm I am 100% certain. Looks like it was the use of Vue.js {{ }} template tags that was throwing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whitespace in your codeblock is what's throwing it off. Instead of this:

```
<code class="block whitespace-pre overflow-x-scroll">
   {{ dataset.bibTex }}
</code>
```

Do this:

```
<code class="block whitespace-pre overflow-x-scroll" v-text="dataset.bibText"></code>
```

Or even this:

```
<code class="block whitespace-pre overflow-x-scroll">{{ dataset.bibTex }}</code>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `white-space: pre;` means you have to be careful of the whitespace in your editor. Here's some examples:

```css
code.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<code>
  test
</code>

<hr/>

<code class="pre">

  test
  dfgdkfhdfg
  
</code>

<hr/>

<code class="pre">
         test
            dfgdkfjgh
</code>

<hr/>

<code class="pre">
test
dfgdkfjgh
</code>
```

Try this instead:

```
<code class="block whitespace-pre overflow-x-scroll">
{{ dataset.bibTex }}
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks for this considered answer - just to show you the curtsey I have chosen the other answer as it has some interesting Vue related features (use of v-text directive). Thank you for the time spent tho to answer. +1 voted!